# How to 3D model a shirt (from an image - man wearing a shirt)? Need to put the shirt on a different 3D character in Blender. New to blender

Tags: objects, import

Problem statement - I want to show in 3D (superimpose) how a piece of cloth (say shirt) from a 2D image will look like on a 3D character of another person. How can I import just the shirt on blender and add to the 3D character? Very new to Blender. Tried researching a lot with no background in this field but couldn't find anything.

Many thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather large question actually. If you need a full 3d solution, you will have to post some time in learning Blender, as You will need to model the clothes, UV unwrap the clothes and create textures from images taken of original product, and create materials from these.

You can then apply something like the [cloth simulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q06lPp2PNG4)

But it is a large task. If You are looking for a 3D gimmick to a webshop or the like, it is a lot of work. So please consider if it is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and guidance. At least now I know that it is possible. Will dig deep into it. I think it will not be very big an effort if I can get the 3D model file from the apparel designer; if they do that for every garment.